# com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: unconfigured table peers_v2

Tags: java, cassandra, newrelic, datastax-java-driver, spring-data-cassandra

I am developing an application with Spring Boot that connects to cassandra

This is my connection settings

```
spring.data.cassandra.contact-points=localhost
spring.data.cassandra.keyspace-name=sa_tas_db_cassandra
spring.data.cassandra.schema-action=create_if_not_exists
spring.data.cassandra.username=cassandra
```

I'm just using a table, which I create by means of a model. Which is the following

```
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.mapping.PrimaryKey
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.mapping.Table
import java.time.LocalTime
import java.util.*

@Table
data class CallLog(
    @PrimaryKey
    val callId:UUID,
    val CustomerUsername: String? = null,
    val callDirection: String? = null,
    val callingPartyName:String? = null,
    val callingPartyNumber:String? = null,
    val calledPartyNumber:String? = null,
    val typeOfCall:String? = null,
    val startTime: Date? = null,
    val answerTime: LocalTime? = null,
    val disconnectTime:Date? = null,
    val timeCallForwarded: Date? = null,
    val voicemailSystemAccessNumber:String? = null
)
```

That's all my cassandra setup

I am also monitoring my application with new relic, and it is generating the following problem

```
….netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:99)
…hannel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:377)
…hannel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:363)
….channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:355)
  io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:286)
…hannel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:377)
…hannel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:363)
….channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:355)
…etty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:102)
…hannel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:377)
…hannel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:363)
….channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:355)
…tty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:321)
…o.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:295)
…hannel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:377)
…hannel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:363)
….channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:355)
…netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelRead(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:93)
…hannel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:377)
…hannel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:363)
….channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:355)
…channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
…hannel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:377)
…hannel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:363)
…o.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
….channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:163)
   io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:714)
….channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:650)
  io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:576)
                  io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493)
….netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
         io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
   io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
```

This error does not affect the operation of the application, it only affects the performance

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a part of compatibility test for supporting Cassandra 4.0 that stores information about nodes in the cluster in a table with different name, so driver first assumes that it runs against newer version, and checks this table, and if it receives an error, then it uses the old `peers` table. It's not possible to reliably detect Cassandra node's features only from version number, that's why it's better to check for table explicitly.

The corresponding code is [here](https://github.com/datastax/java-driver/blob/3.x/driver-core/src/main/java/com/datastax/driver/core/ControlConnection.java#L92).